# Database in recovery mode

Tags: server, slq-server-2019

My database is entered in recovery mode due to power loss while executing query! I have tried a lot of queries but i am unable to resolve that problem

Answer (score 1):

I would start with:

```
Restore database <db_name> with recovery
```

If that is not working look at the "Current" "SQL Server Logs" and check for errors.